# Invalid YAML: inconsistent indentation: addresses: [192.168.1.120/24]

Tags: networking, 20.04, kvm-virtualization, netplan, qemu

In my host Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop, I'm creating 2 bridges for eth0-br0 and eth1-br1.
br1 needs LAN access from the host machine 192.168.1.120/24 to the guest machine 192.168.1.1/24.
I haven't been able to find any info on a static IP address for a bridge, so I tried this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/netplan$ cat 01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.120/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4]
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
    br1:
      dhcp4: no
        addresses: [192.168.1.120/24]
        gateway4: 192.168.1.1
        nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4]
      interfaces:
        - enp2s0
```

However running netplan shows error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/netplan$ sudo netplan try
/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml:21:18: Invalid YAML: inconsistent indentation:
        addresses: [192.168.1.120/24]
                 ^
```

Comment: I'm no YAML expert but could it be that you mix tab characters and spaces?

Comment: Shouldn't' `addresses`, `gateway4` and `nameservers` be indented at the same level as `dhcp4`?

Comment: Please see the example templates at /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples. I believe that the details and indentation in your file are not correct.

Comment: Comment1: I have only used Tabs for indentation.  Comment2: My indentation is exactly as per https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setting-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu-linux-ip-address-tutorial/  Comment3: I see no share directory in my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop?

Comment: What does this tell you? `ls /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples` Tabs are not permitted.

Comment: Ok, examples loaded.  I don't see a bridge static ip example.  bridge_vlan example is there but I'm not sure if that would be for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed yaml output. The main problem was your br1 indentation.

```
#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.120/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4]
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
    br1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.120/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4]
      interfaces:
        - enp2s0
```